# Mixing square waves

Tags: frequency

I want to mix two square waves of different frequencies together - I'm driving a speaker, and I'd like to play two frequencies at once on it (to whatever extent that is possible). I would just add the two signals together, but then the output signal needs to be capable of three voltage levels (if the original signals can be either 0 or 1, then the output signal could be 0, 1, or 2), but my output signal is only capable of being low or high. What is the best way I can go about this?

Comment: Could you explain for what purpose you want to mix?

Comment: I'm driving a speaker, and I'd like to play two frequencies at once on it (to whatever extent that is possible)

Comment: If you're driving a speaker, you most definitely would not want to restrict yourself to 0 and 1, where does that restriction come from?

Comment: The device I'm using to drive the speaker is only capable of outputting high or low voltage levels.

Comment: I'd recommend you look into what a class-D amplifier is, then! (in short, you can use that device, but you need to switch it much faster than the frequency of your signals - but that's probably not a problem)

Comment: The problem here really is that what you *want* is in conflict to what you *demand*; could you maybe explain for which purpose you're driving the speaker with square waves?

Comment: This is the ideal application for a Delta Sigma DAC which only puts out two analog levels, and then use an analog low pass filter prior the speaker input. This can be implemented with modest oversampling ratios (if a higher order DAC is used)

Comment: Thanks. I don't really have hardware on me, so I was looking for a software solution for the mixing. So, I am sort of stuck with finding some way to drive the speaker with square waves only. Are you saying that it isn't really feasible to play multiple frequencies with a square wave?

Comment: Yes completely feasible, and FAT32's answer is the simplest way to combine the two. If you can oversample, the Delta Sigma DAC is implemented in software: See this https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69004/how-does-the-worlds-simplest-sigma-delta-dac-work

Comment: Thank you!! OR-ing the signals seemed a bit too easy, so I was skeptical at first. I will try out both and report back.

Comment: I'm glad if that helped. Honestly what I understood from your prolem was that you wanted to add with clipping two square waves of 0/1 levels at different frequencies. The OR gate provides this exactly, however as it's clipped; it's nonlinear, and superposition do not apply;i.e. the sum has a different effect than the sum of individual effects. A class D amplifier (as @MarcusMüller suggested) is driven by a comparator and its ouput is PWM (variable duty cycle square wave).

Comment: So, simply OR-ing the signals together works decently. How does the class D amplifier come into play? If I understand correctly, instead of adding two square waves together, I could add two sine waves together, pass the result into a class-D amplifier, and drive the speaker with the output? Would I have to build a low-pass filter before driving the speaker?

Comment: @user403069 again, what is the purpose of all this? You can do a lot of things. Whether or not they make the least sense for your application depends on your application. You can't expect us to answer what will work for you if all of us are only agreeing in one thing: what you want is kind of unclear.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have an FPGA that I can program and I want to connect an I/O port directly to a speaker. I'd like to play two sounds of different frequencies simultaneously on the speaker. I have limited components, so I'd prefer doing all the mixing in software and just connecting the output directly to my speaker.

Comment: well, if you want to play one (or two) sounds of specific frequencies, then square waves is not what you want, as you'll notice when looking at the Fourier series of a square wave: it has harmonics, and strong ones, at every odd multiple of the fundamental frequency.  That's why your single square wave already doesn't sound nice but like ... a square wave sounds. So, really, calculate a sine wave in your FPGA (easy: with DDS, easy if ready-made: with a CORDIC), and convert it to PWM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple continuous input OR gate will do your job for strict waves of 1/0 amplitude levels.

The following is a matlab simulation of the logic OR functionality with continuous inputs.

```
N = 1024;
p1 = sin(2*pi*3.5*[0:N-1]/N) > 0  ;
p2 = sin(2*pi*15.5*[0:N-1]/N) > 0  ;

figure,subplot(3,1,1)
plot(p1);title('square wave 1');
axis([1,N,-0.5,1.5])
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(p2);title('square wave 2');
axis([1,N,-0.5,1.5])
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(p1 | p2);title('the OR summed waves');
axis([1,N,-0.5,1.5])
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: An XOR provides the product, or a Modulo-2 addition, but doesn't accurately provide the Add per the OP's description. (If according to an addition, the OP wants the result to represent both frequencies and not the sum and difference of both frequencies as the above would provide (as well as that of all odd order harmonics, and odd order harmonics of the results given the signals are square waves).

Comment: I didn't use XOR, (though I thought at first) this is just plain OR. It's unconventional but just to get the sum of binary level square waves. It only converts 2 into 1 when both are on... Don't know if this is useful for him as an **addition** of two waves. As you indicate there are different conventions for *mixing* binary waves...

Comment: I deleted my answer -- it is clearly simply this as you put and therefore very useful (Once I mapped 0 and 1 to +/-1 where you can get -2, -1, +1, +2 ---and then take the sign, if you do the truth table of that it is the OR gate. I overthunk it!

Comment: @DanBoschen You didn't have to delete your answer. That also provides more sophistacated approach (compared to my naive or) along with simulation results which are quite valuable...

Comment: It was a misleading answer suggesting extra steps were necessary when I then realized thanks to your post that instead of adding 0 and 1 and then dealing with the tie with random distributions (ugh!), simply add -1 and 1 instead and you never get the condition of the tie! And then that reduces to what is simply an OR, just as you stated. So not very naive at all!